# Adding DataGridCheckBoxColumn column to DataGrid programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, datagrid

I have in my project a xaml grid where I'm using checkbox our requirement is changed now we are constructing datagrid programatically how can I use xaml in csharp. following is the example I have checkbox column in xaml

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
       <CheckBox x:Name="chkHeader" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                   <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,   
                           ElementName=chkHeader, Mode=OneWay,
                           UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Here programatically I'm creating a grid

```
foreach (var field in dc.AllColumns)
 {
     var binding = new Binding(".") { Converter = new  
        IndexingDataFieldsConverter(field) };
        AudioPlayBackGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn { Header = 
          field.Field.Description, Binding = binding});
  }
```

and here I'm injecting check box programatically that I have in xaml so far I have done

```
    Binding columnbinding = new Binding("IsChecked");
    columnbinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;
    columnbinding.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource
    (RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor);
    columnbinding.RelativeSource.AncestorType = datagrid.GetType();

    CheckBox chkHeader = new CheckBox();
    chkHeader.Content = "ALL";
    chkHeader.SetBinding(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty, columnbinding);
    DataGridCheckBoxColumn checkBoxColumn = new   
    DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
    checkBoxColumn.Header = chkHeader;
    checkBoxColumn.Binding = columnbinding;
    AudioPlayBackGrid.Columns.Add(checkBoxColumn);
```

Somehow I cannot do in csharp what I did in xaml grid any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

You can try such an approach to add columns programmatically:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGridTextColumn dgTextColumn = new DataGridTextColumn();
    dgTextColumn.Header = "ID";
    dgTextColumn.Binding = new Binding("ID");
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(dgTextColumn);

    DataGridCheckBoxColumn dgCheckBoxColumn = new DataGridCheckBoxColumn();
    dgCheckBoxColumn.Header = "IsChecked";
    dgCheckBoxColumn.Binding = new Binding("IsChecked");
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(dgCheckBoxColumn);

    DataGridTextColumn dgTextColumn2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
    dgTextColumn2.Header = "Name";
    dgTextColumn2.Binding = new Binding("Name");
    dataGrid1.Columns.Add(dgTextColumn2);

    dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Item() { ID = 1, Name = "Someone1", IsChecked = true });
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Item() { ID = 2, Name = "Someone2", IsChecked = false });
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Item() { ID = 3, Name = "Someone3", IsChecked = true });
    dataGrid1.Items.Add(new Item() { ID = 4, Name = "Someone4", IsChecked = false });
}
```

And Model:

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @jayraja feel free to ask any question